# Image Blob URL generated from URL.createObjectURL() is broken when opening in new tab

Tags: node.js, reactjs, file, url, blob

I am trying to open documents fetched via APIs sending BLOB data in a new browser tab using a react/node.js app. The code is working for me for application/pdf but not working for any image files like pdf, jpeg etc. After fetching in the data(arrayBuffer) I am changing it to Blob and then creating the URL. Below is the code for the same.

```
previewDocument("param1", "param2")
  .then((res) => {
    const blobWithType = new Blob([res], { type: res.type });
    const urlToPreview = URL.createObjectURL(blobWithType);
    window.open(urlToPreview, "_blank").focus();
  })
```

The above code is opening a new tab but it simply shows a broken image not the actual image. In firefox it called out clearly that there is an issue with the image.

I have tried to use files that I uploaded myself instead of fetching BLOB data but same has failed as well. Both result a broken image. **Please note, this is working for text/html, application/pdf files.**

Answer (score 0):

The `Blob` constructor expects an iterable with elements that are "ArrayBuffers, TypedArrays, DataViews, Blobs, strings, or a mix of any of such elements".

It's very likely you're passing an array with a `Response` object to the `Blob` constructor. `Response` is not any of the acceptable types, but it can be converted to a string, and so the blob data is the string `"[object Response]"`.

It's better to use the `Response.blob()` function, which works just like `Response.json()` or `Response.text()`.

```
previewDocument("param1", "param2")
  .then((res) => res.blob())
  .then((blobWithType) => {
    const urlToPreview = URL.createObjectURL(blobWithType);
    window.open(urlToPreview, "_blank").focus();
  })
```